# If app is signed-in in a new window, It should stay signed-in in another tab but should not stay signed-in in another window

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

Currently below is how login / logout functionality of our app works,
1.  Choose a browser (lets assume we choose chrome)
2.  Login to our web app in a chrome window
3.  Open the web app in another tab/window (The app is already logged in)
4.  Logout the web app in another window (The app is logged out in all the window / tabs)
NOTE: Above steps work the same way in all browsers(ex: chrome, firefox, IE etc)

Below is what we want to achieve,
1.  When the app is signed-in in a new window, It should stay signed-in in another tab but should not stay signed-in in another window.

Also when a tab where the app is opened is dragged from the window, It becomes a new window(So it should logout and asks for login)

Comment: As a general rule here one wants some example code that you are working on that is trying to do what you want to achieve, but does not work the way you want it to. You should show the html, and the javascript you are using and describe where it falls short of your wants.

Comment: I am not aware of any way that you can tell the difference between if you are in a new window or a new tab. therefore I believe part of what you want is not doable. If the requirements just apply to windows or tabs opened from within your application (e.g you have a link open new window, and open new tab) I believe you would be able to do something, although different browser restrictions might mean you cannot force a window to open as a tab or window if the users have set a default rule for how new documents should be opened.

Comment: @user254694 That rule applies to debugging questions ("Why does my code not work?"). Not necessarily to How-to question. I don't really see how adding code here is beneficial.

Comment: @Ivar well first off it would make clearer than the question currently does exactly what the user wants. Second of all it would make it easier to take what they currently have (which they say they have something) and make it do the extra part that is wanted - however as I said in the other comment it is probably not relevant anyway because from the description I don't think what they want is doable.

Comment: @user254694 I fully agree with your second comment. But since Stack Overflow is here to be a resource of questions and answers that are reusable by future visitors, I find it much more valuable to have a general explanation/solution than a very user specific one. Also "It's not possible" is a valid answer. (Hopefully with a good explanation of why that is the case.)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this question you want the following

First: If a user is logged in to your application
And the user opens a new tab by themselves in the browser
And goes to your application url
then the user will be logged in

This can be done via cookies no problem, search the site to find examples, but as I understand it you already have this functionality working.

Second: If a user is logged in to your application
and a user opens a new window by themselves in the browser
and goes to your application url
then the user will be logged out

This is to my knowledge impossible in any browser due to security restrictions, you cannot know from one tab what other tabs are open in the browser window. The only way you could know this is if you used an extension that gave this information, if you think it makes sense to make an extension that helps you do this in your application have a look at the Web Extensions API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions

Comment: Its a requirement to do without extensions. Any other idea is really appreciated.

Comment: In that case, and if my statement of your requirements is correct, then I believe it is not doable due in any mainstream browser.

Comment: sorry typo in last comment, I mean not doable due to security restrictions in any mainstream browser.